# Loop Flow when using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having concerns on how the loop flow works in Python when Recursion is used (never mind the function, just learning about loop flow)

```
def factorial(n):
    print("first line")
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1

    result = n * factorial(n-1)
    print('line after result')
    print('current result is ' + str(result) )
    print('before return result')
    return result
```

In my example I used `factorial(3)` and I'm getting it like this:

```
first line
first line
first line
line after result
current result is 2
before return result
line after result
current result is 6
before return result
6
```

How come I get **line after result** three times after result is computed/returned. Am I not supposed to get it only once after the result? How many times does the loop return the result? I don't understand how recursion loop flow works in python. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `line after result` 2 times(not 3). This line is printed for each return during the recursion calls.

1. You call `factorial(3)`. Python prints `"first line"` and runs a function `factorial(2)`.
2. Python prints `"first line"` and calls `factorial(1)`.
3. Python prints `"first line"` and returns `1`;
4. Gets result from the step 3 and prints `line after result`;
5. Gets result from the step 2 and prints `line after result`;
6. Gets result from the step 1.

Answer (score 0):

With the print statement after the case where n==1 return statement, then the print after will only be printed (in your example) for n = 3, and n = 2.  For n = 1 the statement will not be printed.